# Generic Events Emitted from Component in Angular ~13

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, events

I'm trying to determine if I'm going down an undesirable path with how I'm approaching generic event management in an Angular application.

**The question I have is: Is there a more built-in or best-practices-conforming way to achieve the following.**

---

Given a simple type, representing an item:

```ts
export interface Item {
  name: string;
}
```

I want to create a very generic item list component, that supports emitting actions dictated by the containing component. I've created an `Action` type representing the types of actions that can be emitted, and an `ActionEvent<TPayload>` type representing the emitted action event:

```ts
export interface Action {
  name: string;
}

export interface ActionEvent<TPayload> {
  name: string;
  payload: TPayload;
}
```

The generic item list component is then defined as such:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: "list-component",
  template: `
    <table>
      <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of this.items">
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>
          <button 
            *ngFor="let action of this.actions" 
            (click)="this.doAction(action.name, item)">
            <span>{{action.name}}</span>
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  `
})
export class ListComponent {
  @Input() items: Item[] = [];
  @Input() actions: Action[] = [];
  @Output() onActionEvent: EventEmitter<ActionEvent<Item>> = new EventEmitter<ActionEvent<Item>>();

  doAction(name: string, payload: Item) {
    this.onActionEvent.emit({name, payload})
  }
}
```

It takes an `@Input` of `items: Item[]` and `actions: Actions[]`; the items to be displayed, and the supported actions of those items respectively.

It also defines an `@Output` of `EventEmitter<ActionEvent<Item>>` to emit events for the items.

The container component then, could be defined as such:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: "container-component",
  template: `
    <h1>Items</h1>
    <list-component
      [items]="this.items"
      [actions]="this.actions"
      (onActionEvent)="this.handleActionEvent($event)">
    </list-component>

  `
})
export class ContainerComponent {
  items: Item[] = [
    {name: "foo"},
    {name: "bar"},
    {name: "qux"},
  ];
  actions: Action[] = [
    {name: "view"},
    {name: "edit"},
  ];

  handleActionEvent(actionEvent: ActionEvent<Item>) {
    console.log(actionEvent);
  }
}
```

This then resembles something such as:

[image: Example UI from above.]

Now, varying containers can define varying actions; some may support `view` and `edit`, others may support different actions. I could easily add a `share` action (*and the corresponding handler code, which could itself be wrapped up in the `Action` type definition*) and have something such as:

[image: Example UI from above.]

Where I'm performing `console.log(actionEvent)`, the container's handler would be responsible for determining what meaningful behavior to perform on `view` or `edit` or whatever else.

So, as stated at the top, am I painting myself into an undesirable corner with this approach? I'm trying to stay very [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), but I feel like I'm straying away from [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). Additionally, I'm as yet unaware of a built-in or more best-practices-conforming way to accomplish this.